# Allow Anonymous if not Forms Based Authenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, single-sign-on

I'm building a web application that should work with Forms Based authentication for SSO within the domain. However, when out of the domain, I'd rather the user connect anonymously instead of seeing that annoying browser popup asking for their Windows authentication. How can I implement this instead of exclusively going forms based or anonymous?

Answer (score 1):

check if the user option returns anything

```
var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

if it does you can check for permissions like what group he belongs or use can use the details to log

other wise assume it is an anonymous   user and don't do what you have to inside a domain